# Avoid double bundle install when using docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker as my dev environment for my rails app with the following `docker-compose.yml` :

```
app:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
    - mail
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
    - gemrc:/etc/gemrc
db:
  image: mdillon/postgis
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=user
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    - POSTGRES_DB=database
  volumes:
    - ./docker/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
mail:
  image: djfarrelly/maildev
  ports:
    - "1080:80"
```

And my `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM rails:onbuild
```

When I need to add a new gem to my Gemfile, I have to first generate my  `Gemfile.lock` :

```
docker run --rm -v gemrc:/etc/gemrc -v /home/user/project:/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app ruby bundle install
```

And the rebuild the docker image:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

Because of this I have to run `bundle install` twice without being able to add the `--without development test` flag. In order to do it quicker I added this to my `gemrc` file:

```
gem: --no-document
```

But **is there a way to avoid the double `bundle install` ?**

Comment: Maybe you might be interested in `bundle install --deployment` and running `bundle package` when you add a new gem, it also saves you some headaches with regards to gem versions.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might want to try the following docker-compose workflow for **development** environment.

1. Similar to database.yml our docker-compose.yml is not included in our CVS (git), providing the similar benefits for developer custom config.
2. Build your image locally before starting your app container and tag it something like *foo_app:latest*. It makes sense because you're in dev. Just execute `docker build .` in your app's root directory, assuming your **Dockefile** is in that directory.
3. Define a **data volume container** for bundle and mount it in your app container. Your docker-compose.yml might look something like:

```
app:
  image: foo_app
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
    - mail
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
  volumes_from:
    - bundle

bundle:
  image: foo_app:latest
  volumes:
    - /home/app/bundle

db:
  image: mdillon/postgis
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=user
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    - POSTGRES_DB=database
  volumes:
    - ./docker/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
mail:
  image: djfarrelly/maildev
  ports:
    - "1080:80"
```

4. Every time you need to add a new gem, just add it to your Gemfile and execute `bundle install` inside your app container. For example if your app container's name is *foo_app_1*:

   `docker exec foo_app_1 bundle install`

   The data volume container will always have the latest/edge *snapshot* of your app's gems.
5. Tag your releases and build the "official release image" in a central repository accessible for your staging/production/team.

With this approach every time you start/recreate your app container, all of your gems be just as they were the last time you updated them. You can also use this approach for other kind of data you want to be persisted across containers life cycles, adding "components" to manage state in your stateless applications.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/ for more information